# What's the default behavior of memcache for MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NO_BLOCK?

Tags: memcached, libmemcached, libmemcache

As is stated in the [doc](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_behavior.html?highlight=memcached_behavior_no_block)

```
"Default behavior is the library strives to be quick and accurate"
```

and

```
MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NO_BLOCK
Causes libmemcached(3) to use asychronous IO. This is the fastest transport available for storage functions.
```

I want to know if the default value for MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NO_BLOCK is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is [`false`](https://github.com/m6w6/libmemcached/blob/b9f2cc374d16fa40dbaf32bb88934d2fc35d4298/src/libmemcached/memcached.cc#L31), you can verify that with [`memcached_behavior_get`](https://m6w6.github.io/libmemcached/libmemcached/memcached_behavior.html#_CPPv422memcached_behavior_getP12memcached_st20memcached_behavior_t).

This behavior is not analogous to `SO_NONBLOCK`/`O_NONBLOCK`/`FIONBIO`, because libmemcached always uses non blocking sockets. See [here](https://github.com/m6w6/libmemcached/blob/b9f2cc374d16fa40dbaf32bb88934d2fc35d4298/src/libmemcached/connect.cc#L207), [here](https://github.com/m6w6/libmemcached/blob/b9f2cc374d16fa40dbaf32bb88934d2fc35d4298/src/libmemcached/connect.cc#L382) and [here](https://github.com/m6w6/libmemcached/blob/b9f2cc374d16fa40dbaf32bb88934d2fc35d4298/src/libmemcached/connect.cc#L467).

It might be due to historic reasons, but nowadays it doesn't do more than [setting `SO_LINGER`](https://github.com/m6w6/libmemcached/blob/b9f2cc374d16fa40dbaf32bb88934d2fc35d4298/src/libmemcached/connect.cc#L312).